# How to check a bcrypt password in java without framework

Tags: java, mysql, bcrypt

I have a login program which takes the information from one db and passes it to the other home section, I want to save an encrypted password (bcript) in the db and in the login it says, for example:
db: `$2a$12$MzhYAeNkuDd/8GaYKPyI5uqe/ANa5sVD3.AdP5TgaFX6MbLTNEkia`
login: `con123`
and allow me to enter.

What should I add to it to do all that?

code:

```
public class CLogin {
    
    private String password ="con123";

    public void validateUser(JTextField user, JPasswordField password){
        try {
            ResultSet rs=null;
            PreparedStatement ps= null;
            
            Classes.CConexionConnectionObject = new Classes.CConexion();
            
            String query="select * from user where user.UserLogin =(?) and user.PasswordLogin=(?);";
            ps=connectionObject.setConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            
            String pass
            String contra = String.valueOf(password.getPassword());
            
            ps.setString(1, user.getText());
            ps.setString(2,con);
            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User is Correct");
                FromMenuMenu object = new FromMenu();
                objectMenu.setVisible(true);
                if (BCrypt.checkpw()){
                    
                }else{
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User is INCORRECT, TRY AGAIN");
            }
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm looking for information on the internet but I can't find anything consistent, or I don't know how to search.

Comment: That code doesn't compile.

Comment: It is not clear where you are stuck. You seem to have a crypt library that you're using (`if (BCrypt.checkpw()){`) but you also seem to use a password in your where clause. What exactly is your question?

Comment: A password hash must be compared to another password hash (using the same salt) for equality. Also, I believe the `BCrypt.checkpw()` method requires parameters.